# BooleanField vs. CharField in Django Models

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

In my app model, I have a `BooleanField`:

```
campaign = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True,
    verbose_name=_('processed'), help_text=_('Campaign or not ?'))
```

I use this to distinguish between two things. So, I thought of sending this value as hidden from an html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="True or False" />
```

but it seems that forms send strings and I want to convert that string into a `Boolean`. Of course, I can re-write the model, make it a `CharField` with a `default='True or False'` value, but that does not seem very elegant.

Is there a more djangoic way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> forms send strings and I want to convert that string into a boolean.

All data in request.POST comes as strings or lists of strings. You need to convert it yourself or use django forms (preferred) which do the the work for you.

With django forms you can replace the widget when you initiate forms.BooleanField like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    campaign = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

[More info on django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow. If I make this override, does it accept the< input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="True or False" />, which is basically a string, from my html form?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Basically, django forms do the conversion for you so you don't need to worry about it. It also allows you to write your own conversion rules.

Comment: django can help you generate the html for your forms. see the doc link in the post above

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try it after reading the forms docs:)